# What is the relationship between an array and its address?

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main (void) {

    int lista[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << lista << std::endl;
    std::cout << &lista << std::endl;
    std::cout << lista+1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &lista+1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << lista+2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &lista+2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << lista+3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &lista+3 << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Outputs:

```
0x22ff20
0x22ff20
0x22ff24
0x22ff34
0x22ff28
0x22ff48
0x22ff2c
0x22ff5c
```

I understood that an array is another form to express a pointer, but we cannot change its address to point anywhere else after declaration. I also understood that an array has its value as the first position in memory. Therefore, `0x22ff20` in this example is the location of the array's starting position and the first variable is stored there.

What I did not understand is: why the other variables are not stored in sequence with the array address? I mean, why `lista+1` is different from `&lista+1`. Should not they be the same?

Comment: *I understood that an array is another form to express a pointer*.  It is not.  Do not think of an array as a pointer.  The are completely different types.  An array will decay to a pointer is many situations but it is not one.

Comment: Useful reading: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: Wrong duplicate, the question is very simple and warrants it's own answer.

Comment: `&lista+1` is not the second element or `lista`. It would be the start of the 2nd `int[5]` array if `lista` was part of an array of `int[5]`s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In pointer arithmetic, *types* matter.

It's true that the *value* is the same for both `lista` and `&lista`, their types are different: `lista` (in the expression used in cout call) has type `int*` whereas `&lista` has type `int (*)[5]`.

So when you add 1 to `lista`, it points to the "next" `int`. But `&lista + 1` points to the location after 5 int's (which may not be a valid).

Comment: Nit: In C++17, the memory model changed so that the two pointers don't actually have the same value - they just happen to represent the address of the same byte. One consequence of this is that in order to `reinterpret_cast` from one to the other, you need `std::launder`, as the types `T` and `T[N]` are not pointer-interconvertible with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question as asked:

```
std::cout << &lista+1 << std::endl;
```

In this code you take the address of array `lista` and add `1` to obtained answer. Given the sizeof of the array is `sizeof(int) * 5`, which means when you increment a pointer to it by 1 you add `sizeof(int) * 5` to the pointer address, you end up with a number you see.